# Add a clause to a MySQL statement without quotes using CodeIgniter's Active Record functions

Tags: activerecord, codeigniter

I wanted to update a row using active records in codeigniter, and I only want to increment a field value (received_qty = received_qty +1) , I realized that I can do that in usual sql, but I cant in codeigniter active records

```
$update['received_qty'] = 'received_qty + 1';
$update['received_date'] = date("Y-m-d");
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->update('vrs_distribution', $update);
```

anyone know how to do it using active records?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This will work.

```
$this->db->set('received_qty', 'received_qty + 1', FALSE);
$this->db->set('received_date', date("Y-m-d"));
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->update('vrs_distribution');
```

ActiveRecord escapes everything put into a set(), where() and many other methods. Where and set can both take an optional third parameter of $escape which is a boolean. Set it to FALSE and CodeIgniter will not escape anything, meaning your field increment wont be treated as a string.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do:

```
$this->db->query('UPDATE vrs_distribution SET received_qty = received_qty + 1, received_date = CURDATE() WHERE id = ' . $id);
```

You would need to modify WHERE clause to suit you though

Answer (score 0):

status set to zero(Update)

```
$this->db->set('IsCurrent', '0');       
$this->db->where('AcademicYearID',$academicYearId);
$this->db->update('academicyear');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to ask a similar question just a little bit different, but the problem was the same: I needed to update a date with an interval (`expiry_date = expiry_date + interval 3 month`) and [*Phil Sturgeon*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2094155/1326147) did solve the problem.

However, what I realized is that you can still use the array for the fields that can have quotes, meaning that you could write:

```
$this->db->set('received_qty', 'received_qty + 1', FALSE);
$this->db->set('expired_date', 'CURDATE() + INTERVAL 10 DAY', FALSE); //extra example 1
$update['received_date'] = date("Y-m-d");
$update['receiver'] = $receiver_name; //extra example 2
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->update('vrs_distribution', $update);
```

Where `$this->db->last_query()` would output:

```
UPDATE `vrs_distribution`
  SET `received_qty` = received_qty + 1,
      `expiry_date` = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 10 DAY, #extra example 1
      `received_date` = '2015-07-01 16:00:00',
      `receiver` = 'strike_noir', #extra example 2
  WHERE #where clause with backticks
```

Notice that the fields where `set()` was used do not have quotes and appear in the first place. The rest of the query has backticks (letting "[CodeIgniter protect the remaining fields](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)").

Answer (score -2):

You seem pretty close, there isn't an 'increment by one' command in CI's ActiveRecord (or in SQL for that matter).

```
$update['received_qty']++;
$update['received_date'] = date("Y-m-d");
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->update('vrs_distribution', $update);
```

Comment: Sorry buddy but there is, ActiveRecord simply escapes all input as a string unless told otherwise.

Comment: Must have been late, or I hit the bar early. Whoops.