# Perform arithmetic within MySQL UPDATE query formed using CodeIgniter's Active Record class

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, sql-update

I'm using `$this->db->update();` to create an update query that adds the value stored in a variable, `$amount`, to the value in a column, `count`. My function call currently looks like this:

```
$data = array('count' => 'count + '.$amount);

$this->db->where('id', $item_id);
$this->db->update('items', $data);
```

However, this generates the following broken SQL:

```
UPDATE `items` SET `count` = 'count + 2' WHERE `id` =  '2'
```

Is there a way to generate the SET clause without the quotes around `count + 2`?

Comment: Did you try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2094155/423235)?

Comment: As Maxime said, this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075984/add-a-clause-to-a-mysql-statement-without-quotes-using-codeigniters-active-reco/

Comment: Thanks, I maybe would have found that solution if it hadn't had a useless title. I was awarded the "excavator" badge when I gave it a new one. Hopefully now others won't have to go to the same trouble I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, [Maxime Morin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/423235/maxime-morin), for putting me on the right track. According to the [CodeIgniter Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert), you can create a "set" clause without quotes by setting the optional `$escape` parameter to `FALSE`. Thus, the solution to my problem was:

```
$this->db->set("count", "count + $amount", FALSE); 
$this->db->where("id", $item_id);
$this->db->update("items", $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the work-around I used until I found my accepted solution

```
$query = $this->db->query("UPDATE `items` SET `count` = `count` + $amount WHERE `id` = $item_id");
```