# How can I update TIMESTAMP with Codeigniter and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

How can I update TIMESTAMP with Codeigniter and MySQL? I want to update with `INTERVAL 1 MINUTE`
I've tried the next code:

```
$data = array('is_active' => $state, 
              'timestamp_demo' => "DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)");
$this->db->where('demo_session_id', 'web');
$this->db->update('demo_session', $data);
```

But not work. How can I do?

Comment: have you tried this echo $this->db->last_query() to see what query is generated

Comment: Yes. It generates: `UPDATE `demo_session` SET `is_active` = 1, `timestamp_demo` = 'DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)' WHERE `demo_session_id` =  'web'` But the timestamp field is reset to zero

Comment: you see there date_add is wrapped in commas?

Comment: Did you check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075984/add-a-clause-to-a-mysql-statement-without-quotes-using-codeigniters-active-reco)?  It suggests to use `set()` instead with the last parameter as `FALSE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try your query like this

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE demo_session 
                  SET 
                     is_active = 1, 
                     timestamp_demo = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
                  WHERE demo_session_id = 'web'");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with Active Records, which you're using:

```
$this->db->where('demo_session_id', 'web');
$this->db->set('is_active', $state);
$this->db->set('timestamp_demo', 'DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)', FALSE);
$this->db->update('demo_session');
```

The third parameter in `$this->db->set()` prevents CodeIgniter from escaping the data so it'll use the MySQL function.

It'll end up something like this:

`UPDATE 'demo_session' SET 'is_active' = $state, 'timestamp_demo' = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) WHERE 'demo_session_id' = 'web'`